# How to list the columns from a pandas data frame based on unique value count?

Tags: pandas

I am new to python and I am trying filter out the columns from a dataframe based on the unique value count.
I want to create a list of columns whose unique values count is equal to 3.
Below is my code:

```
cols=objects_ds.apply(pd.Series.nunique) ==3
```

This gives me a dataframe of boolean values(True/False) like below:

```
A FALSE
B FALSE
C TRUE
D TRUE
E TRUE
F FALSE
```

i want my output as below:

```
cols=['C','D','E']
```

But i am not sure how to extract the column names based on the boolean values.
Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need apply here

```
df.columns[(df.nunique()==3)].tolist()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'nunique'

Comment: That's probably because you arent using parantheses. `nunique` is a method.

Comment: @VishnuKunchur that wouldn't case an error, it would simply reference the function itself, rather than the result

Comment: @stujo check your pandas version https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html

Comment: @Wen Thanks,i upgraded the pandas version.no more error and the solution is working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe:

```
ser = df.nunique() == 3
ser[ser.values].index
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer